# Set my time in Fragaria DaterangePicker

Tags: angularjs

Am working on Angularjs. I use a dateRangePicker which is built with directive. How do I set my time into the date range picker?

Date Range Picker reference https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

I tried constructing the date format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ , but still I get naN when I display the date model to date-range-picker

```
<input
      date-range-picker
      type="text"
      ng-model="scheduledDate"
      options="{timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement:30,locale: {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'},separator: '-'}"
/>


$scope.scheduledDate = {startDate:new Date(myDateTime),endDate:new Date(myDateTime)}
```

Am unable to initialize startDate and endDate

Comment: What's your code? Can you share it?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code.

Comment: I have made it Michelem

Comment: I have put the html without tags, since it doesnot show the code i write this HTML in the input tag

Comment: Please have a moment to read how to format you text/code here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help